# Does every group of order $42$ have a normal subgroup of order $3$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups, sylow-theory

> Does every group of order $42$ have a normal subgroup of order $3$?

I have both Sylow Theorems I can use. They imply that there are either $7$ or $1$ Sylow $3$-subgroups and the $7$ case is what makes me doubt whether the statement is true or false.

Can anyone please help me either prove or disprove this statement?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: *Hint*: Look at the nonabelian group $F_{21}$ of order 21.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint.
Group of order 42
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\mathbb{Z}_7^* & \mathbb{Z}_7\\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix} 
$$
has no normal subgroup of order $3$.

Check.

Comment: This is the affine group [${\rm Aff}(\Bbb F_7)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_group).

Comment: @DietrichBurde Yes, quite right.